# Why header() doesn't redirect me correctly?

Tags: php, url-routing

Here is my website's folder structure:

```
myweb/
    index.php
    files/
        autoloader.php
        login.php
```

And here is my script:

```
// login.php

class login{

    public function __construct () {
        function signed(){
            header('Location: ../');
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function index(){

        echo isset($_SESSION['error_message']) ? $_SESSION['error_message'] : null;

        if ( $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ) {
            signed();
        }

        $_SESSION['login'] = 1;

        if ( $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ) {
            $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'something is wrong';
            header('location: ../login');
        }
    }
}
```

When I load this path:

```
localhost/myweb/login
```

Here is two cases:

1. `$_SESSION['login']` is equal to `1`: My script redirects me to this path: `localhost/myweb`
2. `$_SESSION['login']` isn't equal to `1`: My script redirects me to this path: `localhost`

The first case is fine, I mean it works as expected. But the second case is wrong, I mean it doesn't work as expected. In the second case, it should redirect me to this path: `localhost/myweb/login`. Well how can I fix it?

**Note:** All pages pass through the `index.php`.

Comment: Try this:
            header('location: /login');

Comment: @user4887505 Wrong .. In your case it redirects me to this path `localhost/login` which is invalid.

Comment: if you load "localhost/myweb/login"  path and

 $_SESSION['login'] isn't equal to 1

here you are already in login  file, so why you redirect page?

Comment: @user4887505 Actually I need to redirect a page to itself. In other word I need to **refresh** a page. In reality I'll fill a session like `$_SESSION['error'] = 'something';` and I need to refresh the page to show that error to the user.

Comment: To refresh the page please try this one after $_SESSION['error'] = 'something';  : header("Refresh:0");

Answer (score 0):

You can use ob_start(); on top of the page  and ob_end_flush();  after header . It should work 
last option you can use JavaScript for redirecting the page

```
ob_start();
```

class login{

```
public function __construct () {
    function signed(){
        header('Location: ../');
        ob_end_flush();
        exit;
    }
}

public function index(){
    if ( $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ) {
        signed();
    }

    $_SESSION['login'] = 1;

    if ( $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ) {
        header('location: ../login');
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I don't see any condition of `$_SESSION['login']` being compared as not equal (`!=`) to `1`.

And this part does not make any sense,

```
$_SESSION['login'] = 1;

if ( $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ) {
    $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'something is wrong';
    header('location: ../login');
}
```

you always set the session login to `1`, thus there's no way it will enter to that condition.